# Putting JSON data into a structured output

Tags: python, json, output

I need help putting all the information in a JSON file into a structured output. The JSON is this:

```
[{"id":13076,"title":"Super Conference","coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC"},{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-07-13T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-18T00:11:59+01:00","description":"July 13, 2018 - July 15, 2018. Starting at 8 a.m to 8 p.m Location: 283 Duke Street West, Kitchener ON, Canada.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/f7b766bc8fdbb39111ee949afcb2c56b.png","source":"https:\/\/blockchainsuperconference.com","is_hot":false,"vote_count":38,"positive_vote_count":32,"percentage":84,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":null,"tip_adress":null,"twitter_account":null,"can_occur_before":false},{"id":13071,"title":"ETHGlobal Hackathon","coins":[{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-09-07T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-17T17:04:20+01:00","description":"Hackathon, workshops and talks in Berlin.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/8d0c30eb00cbf791b74f4819f5fb097a.jpeg","source":"http:\/\/ethberlin.com\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":25,"positive_vote_count":22,"percentage":88,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"},{"id":6,"name":"Community Event"},{"id":7,"name":"Other"}],"tip_symbol":"LTC","tip_adress":"LKj8TgPzqDZMUxGRhL92yVJxMv8ZbZfr8E","twitter_account":"@Sokercat","can_occur_before":false},{"id":12872,"title":"Devcon4","coins":[{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-10-30T00:00:00+00:00","created_date":"2018-05-14T03:00:38+01:00","description":"Devcon\u2019s purpose-to serve the global community of Ethereum developers, designers and ecosystem-builders to connect, learn and share.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/21f5a2e868ee750fe1c2b0af877339d4.png","source":"https:\/\/blog.ethereum.org\/2018\/05\/11\/devcon4-announcement\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":28,"positive_vote_count":22,"percentage":79,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":"ETH","tip_adress":"0x1Fff560EBCcCF3DDD7d9Fd77C00242dA5D62b271","twitter_account":"@neogeojr","can_occur_before":false},{"id":12675,"title":"Distributed 2018","coins":[{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"},{"id":"poet","name":"Po.et","symbol":"POE"},{"id":"vechain","name":"VeChain","symbol":"VEN"}],"date_event":"2018-07-19T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-08T18:49:53+01:00","description":"Distributed 2018 occurs in San Francisco from July 19-20.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/09e50e8a61f872c1a6d8891495636d4d.png","source":"http:\/\/2018.distributed.com\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":102,"positive_vote_count":91,"percentage":89,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":null,"tip_adress":null,"twitter_account":null,"can_occur_before":false}]
```

I want to take all the date_event, description, and percentage and output it like this (multiple entires based on the amount of information in the JSON):

```
Date: 2018-07-13 (not sure how to remove the stuff after T in 2018-07-13T00:00:00+01:00)
Description: Hackathon, workshops and talks in Berlin.   
Percentage: 79
```

I know how to get the json info by doing something like

```
for i in json:
    date = i['date_event']
```

but i'm not sure how to put everything in order to make them together.

thanks !

Comment: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689120/2685624)

Comment: Don't "remove the stuff after T"! it's very important to understand and incorporate the timezone information!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` package and make sure the JSON is in a string using quotation marks, such as:

```
import json

spam = '[{"id":13076,"title":"Super Conference","coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC"},{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-07-13T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-18T00:11:59+01:00","description":"July 13, 2018 - July 15, 2018. Starting at 8 a.m to 8 p.m Location: 283 Duke Street West, Kitchener ON, Canada.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/f7b766bc8fdbb39111ee949afcb2c56b.png","source":"https:\/\/blockchainsuperconference.com","is_hot":false,"vote_count":38,"positive_vote_count":32,"percentage":84,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":null,"tip_adress":null,"twitter_account":null,"can_occur_before":false},{"id":13071,"title":"ETHGlobal Hackathon","coins":[{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-09-07T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-17T17:04:20+01:00","description":"Hackathon, workshops and talks in Berlin.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/8d0c30eb00cbf791b74f4819f5fb097a.jpeg","source":"http:\/\/ethberlin.com\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":25,"positive_vote_count":22,"percentage":88,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"},{"id":6,"name":"Community Event"},{"id":7,"name":"Other"}],"tip_symbol":"LTC","tip_adress":"LKj8TgPzqDZMUxGRhL92yVJxMv8ZbZfr8E","twitter_account":"@Sokercat","can_occur_before":false},{"id":12872,"title":"Devcon4","coins":[{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"}],"date_event":"2018-10-30T00:00:00+00:00","created_date":"2018-05-14T03:00:38+01:00","description":"Devcon\u2019s purpose-to serve the global community of Ethereum developers, designers and ecosystem-builders to connect, learn and share.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/21f5a2e868ee750fe1c2b0af877339d4.png","source":"https:\/\/blog.ethereum.org\/2018\/05\/11\/devcon4-announcement\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":28,"positive_vote_count":22,"percentage":79,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":"ETH","tip_adress":"0x1Fff560EBCcCF3DDD7d9Fd77C00242dA5D62b271","twitter_account":"@neogeojr","can_occur_before":false},{"id":12675,"title":"Distributed 2018","coins":[{"id":"cryptocurrencies","name":"Cryptocurrencies","symbol":"CRYPTO"},{"id":"ethereum","name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"},{"id":"poet","name":"Po.et","symbol":"POE"},{"id":"vechain","name":"VeChain","symbol":"VEN"}],"date_event":"2018-07-19T00:00:00+01:00","created_date":"2018-05-08T18:49:53+01:00","description":"Distributed 2018 occurs in San Francisco from July 19-20.","proof":"https:\/\/d32bfp67k1q0s7.cloudfront.net\/09e50e8a61f872c1a6d8891495636d4d.png","source":"http:\/\/2018.distributed.com\/","is_hot":false,"vote_count":102,"positive_vote_count":91,"percentage":89,"categories":[{"id":5,"name":"Conference"}],"tip_symbol":null,"tip_adress":null,"twitter_account":null,"can_occur_before":false}]'

eggs = json.loads(spam)

for entry in eggs:
    for key, value in entry.items():
        print(key, value)
```

edit: You could also use the built in `str` function like:

```
spam = str(JSON_stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Thursdays Coming's answer:

Filter your outputs like this:

```
for entry in eggs:
    print 'Date:', entry['date_event'][:10]
    print 'Description:', entry['description']
    print 'Percentage:', entry['percentage']
    print ''

# Date: 2018-09-07
# Description: Hackathon, workshops and talks in Berlin.
# Percentage: 88
# 
# ...
```